# What does :Automatic in a function definition mean

Tags: functions

I've been trying to figure it out, to no avail. In reading someone else's code, I come across a function definition, where it says something like this

```
UserDefinedFunction[a_Integer, b_Integer, c_Integer, d_, k_:Automatic]/;Abs[a]>b:=0;
```

I understand that it means the function should return 0 if Abs[a] > b, but what does the tag `Automatic` in `k_:Automatic` mean? What is it broader usage? How does it relate to when I plot something and tell Mathematica to assign `PlotRange -> Automatic`?

Comment: It is not a tag, it is a default value for pattern `k_`. e.g. if you call UserDefinedFunction[1,2,3,4], then `k` will be considered as `Automatic`. As for what `Automatic` really means depends on the definition of the function, it could be used like `Plot[...,PlotRange->k]` which means that by default the resulting plot will have automatic plot range, or you might use it just as a symbol, e.g. `k+1`, which returns `Automatic+1` if nothing is assigned to `k`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FullForm[k_: Automatic]
(* Optional[Pattern[k,Blank[]],Automatic] *)
?Optional
```

> p : v is a pattern object that represents an expression of the form p, which, if omitted, should be replaced by v

So, if you omit the argument, `Automatic` is what will be used.

Comment: Does it mean that if I omit k as the function argument, and only call UserDefinedFunction[a, b, c, d], then the function would be evaluated as if k is not defined at all?

Comment: No, it means that the function would be evaluated as if k is given as `Automatic`.

Comment: Okay, so is `Automatic` a type in this case?

Comment: @Morgan It's just a symbol. It could be anything else. The specific values used here (i.e. Automatic) is irrelevant to your question. Check the Optional doc page to understand what the code does.